# Connect to socket.io from C# layer (BLL)

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm tyring to connect to socket client in my Business Login layer (C#)
and send message to socket server (node.js)

but it's goes wrong.

It's connect multiple times and don't create the emit function

Please, can someone help me?
Thank you

```
public void SocketSet(bool b, int action_type)
    {
        if (currentState != b)
        {
            if (b && !connected)
            {
                var obj = new JObject();
                obj["room"] = "Bb";
                obj["content"] = "test";
                obj["from"] = "test";
                obj["dir"] = "left";
                obj["avatar"] = "";
                connected = true;
                manualResetEvent = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
                var options = CreateOptions();
                socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost:3000", options);

                socket.Emit("new-message", obj);

                socket.Open();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess not define socket?

What is socket?